# How to include negative numbers in random number generation

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013

Is this the correct way to generate a random number from (-1, 36)?:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #define RAND_MAX 36

  int main()
  {           
      int num = (-1) + (36 + 1) * (rand()/(RAND_MAX+1));
      printf("%d\n", num);
      return 0;
  }
```

Comment: You don't get to redefine `RAND_MAX`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you know how to get random number in the range zero to `N` (where `N` is whatever max number you want in the range)? Then you know how to generate number in the range `-N` to `N` as well.

Simply generate a number in the range `0` to `2*N` and subtract `N`.

---

Update: To generate a number in the range `-1` to `36`, then you should generate from `0` to `37` and subtract `1`.

The principle is the same in both cases though.

Comment: This is not exactly the answer for [-1;36]

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not the correct way.

First you should not `#define RAND_MAX 36` as `RAND_MAX` is already a define telling the maximum value `rand()` will generate on your system.

A very simple solution is this:

To get numbers in the range [0:37] you can do

```
rand() % 38;  // % is the reminder when dividing by 38 - aka modulo
```

then just `subtract 1

However - see this link for a better distribution

[Why do people say there is modulo bias when using a random number generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984974/why-do-people-say-there-is-modulo-bias-when-using-a-random-number-generator)

Answer (score 0):

That depends on whether you are trying to generate `integers` or `floats` from `-1` to `36`.

~

For `integers`:

1) First, generate a range from `0` to `N`. From `-1` to `36` (inclusive), you have 38 integers.

```
rand()%38; //this generates a range of integers from 0 to 37.
```

2) Shift the range:

```
rand%38 - 1; //this shifts the range of numbers to -1 to 36.
```

~

For `floats` (or numbers with decimal points):

1) generate a "continous" range from `0` to `1`.

```
( 1.0*rand() )/RAND_MAX; //do not forget to convert rand() to a float so that you will not get 0 from integer division.
```

2) Scale the range:

```
37 * ( (1.0*rand() )/RAND_MAX; //this scales the range to (0, 37)
```

3) Shift the range:

```
37 * ( (1.0*rand() )/RAND_MAX - 1; //this shifts to range (-1, 36)
```

Comment: Since op prints with `%d`, integer results must be expected. Your integer solution is just repeating my answer.

Comment: @4386427 He also did write `rand()/RAND_MAX` somewhere in his code. Thus it is not fully clear whether he is expecting an `integer` or `float` range.

Comment: @4386427 That might have been a mistake. It is equally likely that he is expecting a continuous range given that he wrote `rand()/RAND_MAX` also. That is why I provided both an `integer` and `float` solution.

Comment: @4386427 Dont worry, if he is expecting an `integer` range, I will remove my solution. I'm just putting it here for now so that the questioner can take a look at the solution for a continuous range.